# How to Force Show BottomAppBar - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-bottomappbar

In xamarin Android, I have used the bottomappbar as shown below.I have implemented the hide on scroll behavior of BottomAppBar.Scrolling downward hides the bottom app bar. If a FAB is present, it detaches from the bar and remains on screen.Scrolling upward reveals the bottom app bar, and reattaches to a FAB if one is present.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/totalcardview"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/bar"
        android:id="@+id/exppandablerecyclerView"
       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
        android:backgroundTint="#efbe5d"
        app:elevation="1dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bar" />
    <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="70px"
   app:fabCradleMargin="25px"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
           android:backgroundTint="#204060"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
                 android:scaleX="1.3"
                android:scaleY="1.3"
                 android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"></TextView>
            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/stats"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
            <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/statsText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/outline_insert_chart_24"
                android:scaleX="1.3"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
 android:scaleY="1.3"
                android:orientation="vertical"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The bottomappbar hides and shows when I scroll the recyclerview. However I would like to show it when it reaches the bottom of list.How can I force to show the BottomAppBar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide/Show bottomNavigationView on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll)

Comment: @Cheesebaron It does not answer. I want to forcefully show the bottomappbar. Something like Calling performShow() and performHide() on the bottom app bar. But in xamarin android I cant seem to find those methods.

Comment: But if you create your own behavior which shows it when you detect that you've reached the end of the scroll, then you could show it?

Comment: @Cheesebaron hmm ya. Looks like I will have to create my own behavior. Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: The `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior` class provides the **SlideDown** and **SlideUp** method which could help to hide and show the bar. Check the link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55507835/11083277